# Can't Convert List of String into Binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a list for example mylist = ['apple', 'pineapple'] by using

```
[''.join(format(i, 'b') for i in bytearray(mylist, encoding ='utf-8'))]
```

but receive **"encoding or errors without a string argument"**. the expected result is to be

```
['11000011110000111000011011001100101', '111000011010011101110110010111000011110000111000011011001100101']
```

How do I get the result in binary inside a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are applying some of the functions to the wrong objects. You are looking for something like:

```
mylist = ['apple', 'pineapple']

[''.join(format(b, 'b') for b in bytearray(i, 'utf-8')) for i in mylist]
# ['11000011110000111000011011001100101', 
#  '111000011010011101110110010111000011110000111000011011001100101']
```

or a little shorter:

```
[''.join(map('{:b}'.format, bytearray(i, 'utf-8'))) for i in mylist]
```

You must apply `bytearray` to each string in your list, not to the list itself. Next, you must format each byte and join the resulting strings.